# How to see error logs of intellisense in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, intellisense

Does Visual Studio have the Intellisense error logs? If so, how to see them?

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with C++, you can set `Logging Filter` to 8 in `Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Advanced > Diagnostic Logging`. The link: [Validating Project Settings via Diagnostic Logging](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/configuring-c-intellisense-and-browsing/#validating-project-settings-via-diagnostic-logging)

If it is non-C++ project, you can just see the intellisense errors in error list window.